# Scale figure automatically (without enlarging)

Tags: includegraphics, textwidth

I want to use

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example.jpg}
```

or similar to add software screenshots to my Latex file for documentation. The pictures are variable in size and might change over time if the software will be changed.
I want the images to appear in the original dimensions, but if they are too big they need to be downsized to textwidth.
The screenshots should never be enlarged! (blurry, ugly)

Is there a way to decide latex should either use textwidth or the real image size if this size is smaller than the textwidth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `adjustbox` package can help you with this.

The option `max totalsize` limits the size of the content to a given width and height while retaining the aspect ration.

Take a look at the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{%
    max totalsize={\linewidth}{\textheight},
    frame
}
   \includegraphics{car.png} 
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

The option `frame` just draws a frame around the content. This helps evaluating the output especially if you have images with a white background.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: You're welcome!